# How to update a table with subquery using data from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to update a column from a table, and the data i want to put in is the result of a mathematical operation using subquerys that references the update table.

The problem is I want to update every row using data from the same row in the mathematical operation mentioned above.

Here's the example:

```
    UPDATE licenses as lic
    SET lic.numSessions = 
    (
    select difference from
    (select
    (
    select (p.numSessions * p.numMonth) as num from products p
    inner join licenses l on p.idProduct = l.idProduct and l.idpatient = lic.idPatient and l.currentLicense = 1
    )
    -
    (
    SELECT COUNT(distinct s.idSession) as num
    FROM sessions s 
    WHERE s.idPatient = lic.idPatient
    AND s.dateValue >= (select l.dateCreated from licenses l where l.idPatient = lic.idPatient and l.currentLicense = 1) AND s.status = 2
    )
    as difference   
    ) 
    x
    );
```

EDIT:

Example of what i want:

Every row of 'licenses' has a 'idPatient'. Let's call it 'X'.

I want to see how many sessions X has done (for example 10) and then substract this number from the total number of sessions of 'X's' product have (for example 50). So the result in the update for X will be: 50 - 10 = 40.

The subqueries alone work perfectly, I'have the value of 50, then the value of 10, and then when I try to substract I have the value 40 as a column named 'difference'.

The problem I've got is that the query can't recognize the value 'lic.idPatient' inside the first subquery in the substract operation:

```
    /* SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'lic.idPatient' in 'on clause' */
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my writing, I'm not native English.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write query like this

```
UPDATE licenses AS licNew
    SET licNew.numSessions = 
    (
    SELECT x.difference FROM
    ((SELECT
    (
    SELECT (p.numSessions * p.numMonth) AS num FROM products p
    INNER JOIN licenses l ON p.idProduct = l.idProduct AND l.idpatient = lic.idPatient AND l.currentLicense = 1
    )
    -
    (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s.idSession) AS num
    FROM sessions s 
    WHERE s.idPatient = 6361
    AND s.dateValue >= (SELECT l.dateCreated FROM licenses l WHERE l.idPatient = 6361 AND l.currentLicense = 1) AND s.status = 2
    ))
    AS difference, lic.idPatient
    FROM licenses lic
    ) 
    X WHERE licNew.idPatient = x.idPatient
    );
```

In general, you cannot modify a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

Please refer this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-restrictions.html).